How do I limit the hierarchy of work items? For example, only allow tasks to be linked under a bug/requirement, only requirements under epic etc
My dev team creates a mess of planning board by cross linking tickets, creating wrong workitem types all the time. Is there a way to restrict this at a product level?
Only allow following linking
Epic
-- Requirement/Bugs
---- Tasks


I am afraid that there is no such method can limit the work item link behavior for the time being.
Usually, we restrict the behavior of work items through Work item Rules, but currently it does not support setting the work item link field.
Here is a suggestion ticket with the similar requirement: Require Parent for ADO work items (by rule or field requirement)
You can also submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report the feature based on your actual requirement.
